# classLoader.getResource(filename) not returning existent file (returning null)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to load a `.json` file for testing purposes on a Beam pipeline.

The code looks like

```
...
public class ExtractCsvMessageTest {
  @Rule public final transient TestPipeline pipeline = TestPipeline.create();

  final String filepath = "com/project/functions/ExtractCsvMessageTest/";
  final String filename = filepath + "comma_delimited.json";
  final ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

  final File commaDelimited = new File(classLoader.getResource(filename).getFile());
...
```

After running the debugger, I can see the line throwing the error is:

```
final File commaDelimited = new File(classLoader.getResource(filename).getFile());
```

My path looks like

```
test
    ├── java
    │   └── com
    │       └── project
    │           ├── functions
    │           │   ├── ExtractCsvMessageTest.java
    │           └── transforms
    └── resources
        └── com
            └── project
                └── functions
                    └── ExtractCsvMessageTest
                        └── comma_delimited.json
```

There are similar questions on here but I can't find anything which solved this issue.

Also, I'm using VSCode and I just created the path from `resources` manually.

Finally, my `.classpath` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/main" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/main" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="gradle_scope" value="main"/>
            <attribute name="gradle_used_by_scope" value="main,test"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8/"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/default"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="build/classes/test">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="test" value="true" />
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
</classpath>
```

**tl:dr**

Why is

```
final File commaDelimited = new File(classLoader.getResource(filename).getFile());
```

returning `null`?

Answer (score 1):

This was a classpath issue, as suspected.

I solved it in VSCode by triggering the command palette with `Cmd + Shift + P` and selecting

`Java: Clean the Java language server workspace`

This in turn updated the `.classpath` file.

After exitting and launching VSCode again, everything was working again.